# Implementing a locking mechanism for a rotating platform

Tags: design, gears

I have a square platform 2' X 2' X 1". It has clamps on two of its sides that clamp down on the small faces. These clamps are on opposite sides of each other, and they also have shafts sticking out of them away from the platform. These shafts enable the platform to spin about the axis of the shafts 360°. What I need is the ability to lock the platform at different points about this rotation — basically the ability to adjust the tilt of the platform. I figure one option is to fix a spur gear on one side and have a corresponding internal gear that can be moved over or away from the spur gear. The internal gear would rotate with the platform when away from the spur gear. And when the internal gear meshes with the spur gear it would lock the platform at a given rotational position.

This seemed like the most straightforward solution, but after doing some research I didn't really see any examples of it. So I started to get skeptical, as I figured if it was so simple then why would car companies implement [considerably more complicated mechanisms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_MYDqrxi_Q) to accomplish the same thing.

So I'm looking for some advice here as to what would be both a straightforward and economical approach to implementing a rotation lock. Doesn't need to be infinitely granular, would be nice, but the granularity of a 100 tooth spur gear is fine for now. When in the locked position, the platform should not wobble. And the max load on the platform (furthest edge from the axis of rotation) would be 250 lb (static).

Comment: A diagram? But a plate with a locing screw?

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** I recommend either collets or shaft clamping pillow blocks, forces permitting. Collets is probably better, but shaft clamping pillow blocks are definitely easier and cheaper. You can also machine your own pillow blocks to be very wide with multiple screws. Nevertheless, collets are still simpler and cheaper than an actual chuck and should be the most effective solution out of anything here as far as holding force is concerned.

One important thing to note, if your setup is going to be supported on bearing pillow blocks or some other bearing fixture then the shaft clamp needs to close concentrically to not disturb the shaft position. Collets will do this, I do not know if shaft clamping pillow blocks will; They might try and push the shaft off-axis. However,clamping pillow blocks could conceivably support your assembly directly in which case bearing supports are not needed. It might come down to whether you want bearing support as you tilt position your assembly prior to tightening. If using collets you need bearing supports such that when untightened the assembly is supported and rotates on the bearing supports while the loosened collet fixture just floats concentrially the shaft since you do not want to be turning on the collet and marring it. Collets have a discontinuous, interrupted surface and are quite  springy when untightened (i.e. fragile).

---

So...an indexing head? You're looking in the wrong place. Dinky car seat reclining mechanism aren't going to support 250lbs at 2 feet. Look at machine tools where round shafts are clamped under high forces all the time.

You don't see a sliding inner gear lock because it's mechanically complex and gear teeth are fragile. You're trying to use the gear teeth for both indexing and withstanding torque and trying to make up for their fragility by increasing the number of teeth engaged (which may not engage perfectly or consistently) to try and withstand high forces. See indexing heads below for what is actually done.

Infinitely granular is *easier* than an indexing. Just use one of many shaft clamp approach. 250lbs at 2 feet...you're going to want to torque down on that with a giant wrench or allan key and cheater pipe. You might actually need to use an actual lathe chuck or collet for something that big. Good thing they have a hole straight through the bore to hold long workpieces so it can sit midshaft rather than at the end if you wish. Collet is cheaper, easier, and holds better than the chuck since your shaft diameter will be fixed.

[image]
https://www.busybeetools.com/products/5-c-collet-fixture.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwrJOMBhCZARIsAGEd4VEa4EkCHbAGpqIHdqfzcWhXlv2nrB1wQHS0MYdBMCj3cMzTSaS3ARIaAuOhEALw_wcB

[image]
https://www.grainger.ca/en/product/p/WWG35YG66?gclid=Cj0KCQjwrJOMBhCZARIsAGEd4VEo-NZPT-VbrEyrPgcLUkcXYy-QDjLvCO1EzqOrim47dJ8pCco5Sy8aAtTtEALw_wcB&cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=Cj0KCQjwrJOMBhCZARIsAGEd4VEo-NZPT-VbrEyrPgcLUkcXYy-QDjLvCO1EzqOrim47dJ8pCco5Sy8aAtTtEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!3645!3!539417265109!!!g!1404393353019!

If you want positive indexing, the add a notched or holed wheel and spring-loaded pin to the shaft clamp. Indexing heads just used a spring-loaded pin in a notched wheel (essentially equivalent to the inner gear lock as far as indexing is concerned) for *positioning only.* They are then augmented by a shaft clamp to deal with the actual forces. The pin doesn't even need to be spring loaded and you can just remove the pin if you want infinite granularity.

[image]
https://learnmech.com/what-is-dividing-head-used-for-milling-indexing/

[image]
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Components-of-direct-indexing-head_fig1_327680871

Look at angle vises where the entire vise is gimballed between two pillow blocks that have an integral clamping shaft collar you tighten.
[image]
https://www.bearingscanada.com/20mm-Shaft-Support-Pillow-Block-Supporter-p/20-Shaft-Pillow-Block-er.htm?gclid=Cj0KCQjwrJOMBhCZARIsAGEd4VE8WysuEVofeaSgwoRMEBzw-NKB5hP59SqdzG2mjnpFryF_bfviwbcaAt9EEALw_wcB

Also look at drill chucks, lathe chucks...chucks of any kind really.
Note there are multiple types of lathe chucks as well. High accuracy lathe chucks have jaws that ride on a spiral scroll which brings the jaws toward center simultaneously to tighten.
[image]

https://www.mscdirect.com/basicsof/lathe-chucks

[image]

http://www.gts-tools.com/assets/docs/gator-chucks-manual.pdf

Others lathe chucks have independent jaws that each ride on a worm screw you turn to tighten and won't tighten inherently close concentricaly but can hold pieces to be turned on the lathe off center (something you don't need)...they do, however, very high force clamping which you do need but I don't see a good way of getting them to work in your application.
[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_U0Cxrd_KE

Comment: First of all, thank you for the time an effort you put into this post. I wanted to clear up that it's 250 lb only at 1 foot (axis is at the center of the platform so half the distance (2' / 2)) (250 ft-lbs). That said it seems like car seat mechanisms can get pretty close to those tolerances. When the chair is all the way reclined you could conceivably have the equivalent of close to 250 ft-lbs (weight is distributed along the entire back of the chair — for a heavy person this could get relatively close to that figure).

Comment: And if there was one on each side of the platform — both controlled by a single lever — the load bearing capacity would double, and seems like that 250 lb static load threshold would be within reach. That said I see where you're coming from about using gears in the first place. The only issue with some of the solutions you mentioned appear to be that they don't really lend themselves to 'on-the-fly' adjustments.

Comment: @shoe How "on-the-fly" is on the fly?

Comment: The user experience I'm shooting for is for them to be able to release the rotation lock with a single lever that they can trigger with their fingers — the load wouldn't be on the platform when unlocking and rotating, so absent it there wouldn't be much resistance faced when releasing the lock. Knowing that do you still think your two recommendations are good fits.

Comment: Also, these seem like relatively involved mechanical engineering questions. If you happen to be familiar with a resource I can go to to seek paid consultancy on matters such as these, I'd appreciate a reference. It's not uncommon for me to have questions such as these, and it would be nice to just be able to turn to a professional for a quick answer during such times.

Comment: I don't really know a service to be honest. I tend to just ask the toolmaker at work. I mean...the load isn't there on machine tools either when you're loading the workpiece. It kinda matters that it doesn't fly out when under load even if the load is not present during setup.

Comment: I mean, I suppose alternatives to the inner gear lock just the spring-loaded pin and disc I mentioned, except you can use two wheels locating pins and holes all over the face so it essentially becomes just a positive locking clutch. I'm not sure if all pins will equally share the load though due to tolerancing. Or a friction clutch if you trust that, or a clutch with mated serrations on each disc. But those would operate in a motion parallel to the rather than perpendicular to it like the inner gear lock would.